# Establishing a connection between Java server and client within Android appEDIT

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have an app in android in which I created an android client and a Java sever.

But I'm confronting the following issue: my client (the android part) connects to the local machine on port 6000 using the android loopback address.

My server (in Java) listens on local machine at the port 6000 - but what is the IP I have to use to get the socket that accepts the clients?

```
InetSocketAddress serverAddr = new InetSocketAddress(SERVERIP,serverPort);
serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
serverSocket.bind(serverAddr);
```

So what is the SERVERIP I have to use?

UPDATE:My client runns on an emulator!!!!!

EDIT:

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        Object syncToken;

```
    public ClientThread(Object syncToken) {
        this.syncToken = syncToken;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 50458);


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to host");
        }

        try {
            out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }

        while (true) {
            synchronized (syncToken) {
                try {
                    syncToken.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

---

And here is:  private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.2.2";!!!!!

Comment: You mean localhost? 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I don't know????That is what should I use?

Comment: Ok, it looks like the confusion grows :) Do you mind showing us the exact code you use to connect on the client side? What do you mean by 'the android loopback address' exactly?

Comment: Yes...I will edit my question!

Answer (score 2):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking: if you want to communicate from within the emulator to the local host, use IP `127.0.0.1` on the local host and use IP `10.0.2.2` in Android. This should let you communicate between the Android client and the local host server.

Comment: Wow, wasn't aware 10.0.2.2 is routed to outside's loopback. Any idea if it was available from the very beginning?

Comment: As far as I can tell its been there forever: I no longer have the original SDK docs so not sure though. It was a nice hack in the early days and has just stuck around ever since.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run the server part on the Android? I guess not, and in such case using loopback address is not really going to work, as loopback interface on the Android system loops back to the Android machine itself, it is not routed to the outside.

Comment: He's probably running this on the emulator, that's why it's connecting on the same machine.

Comment: This doesn't work either - emulator emulates full system, with its own kernel, TCP stack and loopback interface.

Comment: well....I'm using for my client the loopback android address...The question is what should I use for the server which is on java???

Answer (score 0):

For the serverAddr, use the `#InetSocketAddress(int port)` constructor, it specifies the wildcard address and a specific port, meaning it listens on all the interfaces of the machine.

Edit: For best results, on the android device use the DNS name of the server to connect to it.